# Where does CodeIgniter Retrieve Session Data From?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, timestamp

I am using CodeIgniter to save session data in a database but I noticed that CI also saves some of that session info at the client side. If I need a secure `last_activity` time-stamp how do I know CI is retrieving the one from the database which is secure and not the one from the client side which is not?
Does it match both `last_activity` timestamps to check for validity?

Comment: So what's exactly are you doing, some code example would help.

Comment: @Welling Code is irrelevant here, if you read the question you will understand what I am asking it has really nothing to do with an exact code.

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14464104/codeigniter-what-is-the-point-of-storing-session-data-in-the-cookie-only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my bad, that's what happen when you don't read carefully.

The answer is **YES**, does it has to match both.

This is from CodeIgniter Docs,

> When session data is available in a database, every time a valid session is found in the user's cookie, a database query is performed to match it. If the session ID does not match, the session is destroyed. Session IDs can never be updated, they can only be generated when a new session is created.

So this means yes, it does a matching.

From GitHub (stable 2.1) you can take a look at the database matching process here:

https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/libraries/Session.php#L135

Comment: Thank you just a question out of concern for security.